# Realtime classification of (one of 12) vowel phonemes

Tags: acoustics, cepstral-analysis

I'm attempting realtime classification of (one of 12) vowel phonemes, sung (steady-state-ish) into a microphone.

## MOTIVATION:

Suppose my user sings a MIDI note using a steady-state vowel phoneme (no dipthong etc.) into the microphone.

Each of the 12 pitch-classes has an associated vowel.

So if they sing a 'C', it should always be '[b]ar' sound.
'E' should always be '[be]e'.
'G' should always be '[b]oo'.
etc.

If they sing the wrong vowel-sound for a particular MIDI note, I want to bring it to their attention.

Hence I need to extract (realtime) the frequency they are singing, and the classification of the vowel sound.

The frequency (f0-determination) is a solved problem. However classifying the vowel sound appears harder.

What might be a minimal effective machinery to accomplish this?

## Possible solution paths

The simplest option (upon which I may have to fall back, as a stopgap, as the full problem appears hard) is to invite the user to sing each note with the correct vowel. Then somehow extract a feature-vector (e.g. a cepstrum) for each note as a reference.

## Prior art

I found: https://github.com/sravi1210/Speech-Recognition/blob/master/Vowel_Recognition/Vowel_Recognition/Vowel_Recognition.cpp

However, it refers to non-referenced materials and I'm struggling to infer/reverse-engineer the essential mechanics.

It refers to the 'Tokhura Distance', and I'm able to find a related publication by Tokhura ([here](https://ur.booksc.me/book/18412332/9a98b4)).

Can anyone outline what's going on here, or any other sensible approach?

## ...

I can see that each vowel forms a distinct spectral envelope (formants).
And I can see that there are techniques to reduce the dimensionality of this data (cepstrum/MFCC).

I can guess that eventually I'd be dot-product-ing the feature-vector against 12 preloaded feature-vectors (for my 12 vowels) and picking the winner.

But I don't know how formants vary between speakers. If it's just a linear stretch, one can just divide each formant-centerFreq by that of the first. But life is rarely so simple.

Comment: This is a difficult problem, especially if you want to cover multiple unknown speakers of different age, gender, dialect, ethnicity, etc. "simple yet effective " does not exist for this problem. My recommendation is to start with a crisp set of requirements.

Comment: @Hilmar I've updated the question.

Comment: Understood. Format maps are certainly a good way to go but formant maps depend on a lot of different factors. The question here is how many format maps do you need to build  and how to find which formant maps are the right ones. E.g. will there be a training session for each user?

Comment: I'm treating it as a prerequisite for users to be able to sound the vowels "correctly" i.e. without any trace of regional accent. So I'm left with the variation due to physiology. But I'm also looking for a shortest-path solution. So maybe getting the user to sing the vowels is the best way to get something running, and will allow me to collect training data while I'm at it. The challenge then becomes how to compare the mic-input against the reference WAVs that were collected.